# Compare Two Lists of Dictionaries and Output diffs

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have 2 lists of dicts that I need to compare and output the difference for a report

I need to:

1. Check new_list against old_list for new records (records that exist in new_list but not in old_list) and append these to updated_list
2. Ignore matching records (all key, values match)
3. Find matching records with different event15 or event16 and update the event with the diff of the 2 values
4. Output results to a new list of dicts (updated_list in this example)

To process:

```
new_list = [
{'datetime': '2018-08-01', 'evar1': 'newRecord', 'event16': '100', 'event15': '200'},
{'datetime': '2018-08-02', 'evar1': 'duplicateRecord', 'event16': '10', 'event15': '20'},
{'datetime': '2018-08-03', 'evar1': 'diffEvent', 'event16': '15', 'event15': '25'}
]

old_list = [
{'datetime': '2018-08-02', 'evar1': 'duplicateRecord', 'event16': '10', 'event15': '20'},
{'datetime': '2018-08-03', 'evar1': 'diffEvent', 'event16': '10', 'event15': '25'}
]
```

The results should look like this list:

```
updated_list = [
{'datetime': '2018-08-01', 'evar1': 'newRecord', 'evar3': 'site',  'event16': '100', 'event15': '200'},
{'datetime': '2018-08-03', 'evar1': 'diffEvent', 'evar3': 'site',  'event16': '5', 'event15': '25'}
]
```

I tried this:

```
updated_list = []
for new_item in new_list:
    for old_item in old_list:
        for key, value in new_item.iteritems():
        # If values don't match, subtract old_list value from new_list values and append the diff
        if any(ko == key for ko, vo in old_item.iteritems()):
            ko, vo = [(ko, vo) for (ko, vo) in old_item.iteritems() if ko == key][0]
            if vo != value:
                new_value = value - vo
                new_item.update({ko: new_value})
                updated_list.append(new_item)
            else:
            # If record does not exist in old_list, append the new record
            updated_list.append(new_item)
```

Comment: Try using sets and the `-` (minus) operator to get difference.

Comment: @NChauhan Won't work with dicts!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.  
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.
Your posted code fails to run on for a couple of reasons, and you don't show what you *do* get with the current attempt.

Comment: Among other things, your indentation is off, and you're trying to subtract strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very confusing task indeed! Here is my solution (comments should explain the method).

```
#init a list to store the dictionaries
updated_list = []
#define our 'special keys'
events = ('event15', 'event16')
#remove duplicates from both lists (where all key, values match) - case (2)
old_list_no_dupes = [d for d in old_list if not any(d == dd for dd in new_list)]
new_list_no_dupes = [d for d in new_list if not any(d == dd for dd in old_list)]
for d in new_list_no_dupes:
    #iterate over all the dictionaries in old_list for case (3)
    for dd in old_list_no_dupes:
        #continue to next if not every pair (but event*) matches
        if any(k not in dd or dd[k] != v for k,v in d.items() if k not in events):
            continue
        #iterate the to event keys
        for k in events:
            #check both dictionaries have that key and they are different values
            if k in d and k in dd and d[k] != dd[k]:
                #update the new dictionary to be the absolute difference
                d[k] = str(abs(int(dd[k]) - int(d[k])))
    #append our new dictionary - cases (1), (3) and (4)
    updated_list.append(d)
```

---

```
[{'datetime':'2018-08-01', 'evar1':'newRecord', 'event16':'100', 'event15': '200'},
 {'datetime':'2018-08-03', 'evar1':'diffEvent', 'event16':'5',   'event15': '25'}]
```

Comment: I concur that this was a very confusing task and I hesitated to ask in this forum.  But your solution works perfectly and I can see where I was off target.  Once again the Stack members have an answer. Thank you Joe!!!

Comment: @GreetRufus No problem! Please accept the answer then :) (it's a little tick)